# GeoPandas ValueError: A LinearRing must have at least 3 coordinate tuples

Tags: python, gdal, geopandas, fiona

I am trying to read a multi-polygon GeoJSON file in GeoPandas, but I am getting the following error:

```
'ValueError: A LinearRing must have at least 3 coordinate tuples'
```

command used is `gpd.read_file(layer_file)`

What can I do to filter bad geometry? I converted the dataset from pbf to GeoJSON before reading with GeoPandas. The same GeoJSON file works with QGIS.

Comment: looks like one of your polygon geometry is missing a coordinate point or two.  Have you tried saving with QGIS to geoJSON and then to geopandas.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Figured it out after beating my head for a lot of time.

Change this line

```
gdf = gpd.read_file(layer_file)
```

to

```
#Read data
collection = list(fiona.open(layer_file,'r'))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(collection)

#Check Geometry
def isvalid(geom):
    try:
        shape(geom)
        return 1
    except:
        return 0
df1['isvalid'] = df1['geometry'].apply(lambda x: isvalid(x))
df1 = df1[df1['isvalid'] == 1]
collection = json.loads(df1.to_json(orient='records'))

#Convert to geodataframe
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(collection)
```

don't forget to add these libraries

```
import json
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import shape
```